# Last.variable not returning expected results

Tags: sas

I'm trying to create a summary table from a larger table, using just the last row of data. I have the following code:

```
proc sort data=&data.;
   by date;
run;

data &data._summary;
   set &data.;
   by date;
   if last.date;
run;
```

My understanding is that this should just output one row (for the last value of date), but instead it's keeping all values. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you show the log to help debug, as shown/written it should work? Are you reviewing the summary data set?

Comment: Try `format date` to remove format of `date`, then check if all values are the same.

Comment: The only way it would output only one observations would be if there was only one value of DATE.  That is that DATE was the same on every observation.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation

> **FIRST. and LAST. DATA Step Variables**
> ...
> In the DATA step, SAS identifies the beginning and end of each **BY**
> **group** by creating the following two temporary variables for each BY
> variable:
> • FIRST.variable
> • LAST.variable

If you want the last observation in the DATA set you can use the `END=` option  to set a flag for the last row.

```
data want (label='Last row of have') ;
  set have end=lastrow ;
  if lastrow ;
run ;
```